# Best network design for company with remote offices that need to go through 1 public facing interface

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-vpn

I received a call from a business owner. One of his services will only license and whitelist one public IP well he has three locations. When I got involved they were trying to spin up an OpenVPN appliance and have site to site vpns to the remote locations. Well the remote locations have Fortigate firewalls and this will not work I believe with the SSL VPN of OpenVPN.

I would like to recommend something with Azure or AWS but I am unclear on the best VPN setup with Azure. Essentially he will need all remote sites exiting to the internet through Azure.

Late last night tried to test with AWS VPC and a VPN back to the fortigate. Client later expressed he would rather not use AWS.

Also recommended this https://forum.fortinet.com/m/tm.aspx?m=148626&p=
but he did not want to bottlekneck one of his locations

All sites exiting Azure out of one IP address

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.  You'll have better luck asking this here: https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 sites in Azure, you can make all 3 sites exiting Azure with one VPN gateway IP for the same destination.

You need to configure VNET to VNET peering and enable Gateway Transit to make it work. Can you also elaborate your ask here with a Network Diagram ?

Comment: The end goal was that all sites have one public IP.. He did not share the details of why this is needed but something to do with licensing. They are a call center with 3 remote locations. I ended up setting up a VPC in AWS with 3 site to site IPSec VPN. Confgured the routing so that all internet traffic would ext out of the Nat Gateway.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. As if now, you cannot send Internet traffic to Azure and NAT the traffic to Internet.